# How to define a foreign key using phpMyAdmin GUI in mySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I am creating a table using the GUI in phpMyAdmin mySQL hosted on an Apache web server (XAMMP).

How do I define a column as a foreign key and where do I insert the reference to the corresponding  primary  key? There is a drop down option for Primary Key but I don't see any such option for a foreign key.

[image: The options for each column are as below]
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the Relation view see picture and there you can define our foreign keys.

[image: relation view]

Comment: Correct! You could also use the Designer tool; there's a tab for it from the database page, which gives you basically the same functionality but in a different graphical presentation.